# ¿Como hacer que un DIV no se expanda más alla de sus hijos?

Tags: html, css, responsive

Cordial saludo.

Estoy navegando por el mundo del HTML + CSS y tengo una duda que no logro resolver:

- Como hago para que un div hijo ocupe solo lo que le corresponde y no consuma el resto de la pantalla?

  "Lo que quiero es que el botón de Reservar cita no ocupe el resto de la pantalla"

Adjunto código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>LoQueSeaMi</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="author" content="FelipedelosH" />
  <!-- Incluir Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Incluir Bootstrap JS y dependencias de Popper.js -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>


<style>
  body {
    background-color: aquamarine;
  }
  
  .container_welcome_message {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 4%;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  .welcome_message {
    color: white;
  }
  
  .container_btn_appointment p {
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    margin-left: 8%;
    background-color: #156b40;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  
  .container_btn_appointment svg {
    width: 3%;
    height: 3%;
  }
</style>


<body>

  <div class="container_welcome_message">
    <p class="h1 welcome_message">
      <b>Bienvenido a CDA Anserma</b>
      <br> Realiza aquí la Revisión tecnomecanica.
    </p>
    <div class="container_btn_appointment">
      <p class="display-7">
        Reserva tu cita con nosotros
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-whatsapp" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M13.601 2.326A7.854 7.854 0 0 0 7.994 0C3.627 0 .068 3.558.064 7.926c0 1.399.366 2.76 1.057 3.965L0 16l4.204-1.102a7.933 7.933 0 0 0 3.79.965h.004c4.368 0 7.926-3.558 7.93-7.93A7.898 7.898 0 0 0 13.6 2.326zM7.994 14.521a6.573 6.573 0 0 1-3.356-.92l-.24-.144-2.494.654.666-2.433-.156-.251a6.56 6.56 0 0 1-1.007-3.505c0-3.626 2.957-6.584 6.591-6.584a6.56 6.56 0 0 1 4.66 1.931 6.557 6.557 0 0 1 1.928 4.66c-.004 3.639-2.961 6.592-6.592 6.592zm3.615-4.934c-.197-.099-1.17-.578-1.353-.646-.182-.065-.315-.099-.445.099-.133.197-.513.646-.627.775-.114.133-.232.148-.43.05-.197-.1-.836-.308-1.592-.985-.59-.525-.985-1.175-1.103-1.372-.114-.198-.011-.304.088-.403.087-.088.197-.232.296-.346.1-.114.133-.198.198-.33.065-.134.034-.248-.015-.347-.05-.099-.445-1.076-.612-1.47-.16-.389-.323-.335-.445-.34-.114-.007-.247-.007-.38-.007a.729.729 0 0 0-.529.247c-.182.198-.691.677-.691 1.654 0 .977.71 1.916.81 2.049.098.133 1.394 2.132 3.383 2.992.47.205.84.326 1.129.418.475.152.904.129 1.246.08.38-.058 1.171-.48 1.338-.943.164-.464.164-.86.114-.943-.049-.084-.182-.133-.38-.232z"/>
                </svg>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Adjunto Mockups de que es lo que deseo:

[image: Original]

[image: Deseado]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambié el `div` por un `button` y le asigné tus estilos personalizados. Adicionalmente cambié la etiqueta `<p>` por un `<span>` que es más fácil de controlar en este caso.

Comenta si te quedan dudas.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>LoQueSeaMi</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="author" content="FelipedelosH" />
  <!-- Incluir Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Incluir Bootstrap JS y dependencias de Popper.js -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>


<style>
  body {
    background-color: aquamarine;
  }
  
  .container_welcome_message {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 4%;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  .welcome_message {
    color: white;
  }
  
  .btn-appointment {
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    margin-left: 8%;
    background-color: #156b40;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
</style>


<body>

  <div class="container_welcome_message">
    <p class="h1 welcome_message">
      <b>Bienvenido a CDA Anserma</b>
      <br> Realiza aquí la Revisión tecnomecanica.
    </p>
    <button class="btn-appointment">
        <span>Reserva tu cita con nosotros &nbsp;</span>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-whatsapp" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M13.601 2.326A7.854 7.854 0 0 0 7.994 0C3.627 0 .068 3.558.064 7.926c0 1.399.366 2.76 1.057 3.965L0 16l4.204-1.102a7.933 7.933 0 0 0 3.79.965h.004c4.368 0 7.926-3.558 7.93-7.93A7.898 7.898 0 0 0 13.6 2.326zM7.994 14.521a6.573 6.573 0 0 1-3.356-.92l-.24-.144-2.494.654.666-2.433-.156-.251a6.56 6.56 0 0 1-1.007-3.505c0-3.626 2.957-6.584 6.591-6.584a6.56 6.56 0 0 1 4.66 1.931 6.557 6.557 0 0 1 1.928 4.66c-.004 3.639-2.961 6.592-6.592 6.592zm3.615-4.934c-.197-.099-1.17-.578-1.353-.646-.182-.065-.315-.099-.445.099-.133.197-.513.646-.627.775-.114.133-.232.148-.43.05-.197-.1-.836-.308-1.592-.985-.59-.525-.985-1.175-1.103-1.372-.114-.198-.011-.304.088-.403.087-.088.197-.232.296-.346.1-.114.133-.198.198-.33.065-.134.034-.248-.015-.347-.05-.099-.445-1.076-.612-1.47-.16-.389-.323-.335-.445-.34-.114-.007-.247-.007-.38-.007a.729.729 0 0 0-.529.247c-.182.198-.691.677-.691 1.654 0 .977.71 1.916.81 2.049.098.133 1.394 2.132 3.383 2.992.47.205.84.326 1.129.418.475.152.904.129 1.246.08.38-.058 1.171-.48 1.338-.943.164-.464.164-.86.114-.943-.049-.084-.182-.133-.38-.232z"/>
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias es exactamente lo que estaba buscando. :)

Answer (score -1):

Para aplicar lo que necesitas tenes que colocar los estilos al contenedor llamado '.container_btn_appointment', es decir,

```
.container_btn_appointment {
  display: flex;
}
```

La propiedad flex solo va a realizar que el contenedor hijo solo ocupe el espacio utilizado a menos que le des al ancho un específico. Es posible que tengas que modificar lo estilos de box model para que esto funcione. Por ejemplo, sacar la unidad de posición absoluta.